# How to apply custom formatting for a JSON stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, string, formatting, stringify

I have the following code:

```js
const sample = [
  {
    name: "apple",
    points: [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 5, y: 6 }, { x: 7, y: 8 } ],
    age: 24
  },
  {
    name: "banana",
    points: [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 5, y: 6 }, { x: 7, y: 8 } ],
    age: 45
  }
];

const qwer = JSON.stringify(sample, null, 2);

console.log(qwer);
```

If you run it, you'll notice it has nice formatting, except for the points array, which is extremely verbose.

I would like everything to be indented like normally (which is why I'm passing in 2 for the final parameter to stringify), but I would like the points array to only take a single line, like how it is declared in the code.

The reason for this is because currently each points array is stretched to like 18 lines, when there will only ever be 3 or 4 items. I would like them to stay on one line.

I tried to use a custom replacer, and while it somewhat worked, it forced the JSON array to be a string. But it's not a string. I want it to stay an array.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think you'd have to make a mini-parser that finds the balancing `]` while correctly skipping keys and strings with brackets and accounting for possible nested arrays. Not so hard, but not entirely trivial

Comment: The `points` array is always going to be formatted like that, so it makes it a bit easier. But a custom parser is unfortunate. But yeah, points will ever be an array of 3 or 4 items, each with an x and y parameter (it's a bezier curve).

Comment: I wonder if a fancy regex replace would do the trick..

Comment: Might work in engines that support recursive subpatterns, but unfortunately JS isn't one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general solution, a mini parser would be the best approach, but a quick but ugly-looking approach would be to use a replacer to replace arrays with stringified strings *with a unique value as a prefix* which can be replaced afterwards.

```js
const sample = [
  {
    name: "apple",
    age: 24,
    points: [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 5, y: 6 }, { x: 7, y: 8 } ],
  },
  {
    name: "banana",
    age: 45,
    points: [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 5, y: 6 }, { x: 7, y: 8 } ],
  }
];

const withNestedStringifiedArrays = JSON.stringify(
  sample,
  (key, value) => key && Array.isArray(value) ? '@@UNIQUE@@' + JSON.stringify(value) : value,
  2
);
const output = withNestedStringifiedArrays.replace(
  /"@@UNIQUE@@(.*?)"(,)?$/gm,
  (_, stringifiedArr, possibleComma = '') => stringifiedArr.replaceAll('\\', '') + possibleComma
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: A slight issue with this is that it seems to delete the comma after the array. Looking for a fix now.

Comment: Add an optional comma to the pattern in a capture group, which defaults to the empty string, and append it to the end when replacing

Comment: Hmm that change didn't seem to work for me but just changing `JSON.stringify(value)` to `JSON.stringify(value) + ","` on your original answer works fine. Anyways, thanks again! Works great now.